Problem with SSL Certificate .pem working on PHP and Curl
I am getting this error:

SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

when I have tried consuming an API REST. I had also tried on a server with Linux and the same problem is in.
I found on the web the instructions saying I have to download cacert.pem from the official web cacert.pem and then editing the php.ini file:
[curl]

curl.cainfo = "C:\wamp\bin\php\php8.0.26\cacert.pem"

[openssl]

openssl.cafile = "C:\wamp\bin\php\php8.0.26\cacert.pem"

Now I have the file.pem and these two lines above are currently on my php.ini. As you can see I followed all the instructions, but the problem is going on.
I wrote this line
var_dump(openssl_get_cert_locations());

which returns:
array (size=8)
 'default_cert_file' => string 'C:\Apache24\conf/cert.pem' (length=25)
 'default_cert_file_env' => string 'SSL_CERT_FILE' (length=13)
 'default_cert_dir' => string 'C:\Apache24\conf/certs' (length=22)
 'default_cert_dir_env' => string 'SSL_CERT_DIR' (length=12)
 'default_private_dir' => string 'C:\Apache24\conf/private' (length=24)
  'default_default_cert_area' => string 'C:\Apache24\conf' (length=16)
 'ini_cafile' => string 'C:\wamp\bin\php\php8.0.26\cacert.pem' (length=36)
 'ini_capath' => string 'C:\wamp\bin\php\php8.0.26\' (length=26)

Could you tell me if there is something wrong here?
